# Concentration inequality for independent geometric r.v.

Tags: probability, inequality

Suppose that $Y_k = \frac{1}{k} (X_k - \frac{1}{p})$, for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, where $X_k \sim Geom(p)$ are i.i.d. geometric r.v. such that $\mathbb{E}[X_k] = \frac{1}{p}$, and hence $\mathbb{E}[Y_k]=0$. I want to obtain a concentration inequality of the form

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i \geq \epsilon\ln(n)\right) \leq 1 - \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}},$$

where $\epsilon>0$ and for some $\alpha > 1$.

Firstly, I noticed that $Y_k$'s are independent but not identically distributed because of the extra factor of $1/k$. I then tried to prove it using Chernoff inequality, but I got stuck when I needed to use $\mathbb{E}[e^{tY_k}]$. Do you have any ideas how to prove this?

**Update**

For small enough $t>0$, I have that $\mathbb{E}[e^{tY_i}] \leq e^{t^2\mathbb{E}[Y_{i}^{2}]/2}$, and so

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i \geq \epsilon\ln(n)\right) \leq e^{-t\epsilon\ln(n)} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}[e^{tY_i}] \leq e^{-t\epsilon\ln(n) + \frac{t^2}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[Y_{i}^{2}]}.$$

Let $V=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[Y_{i}^{2}] \sim Cn$, for some constant $C>0$. Then the last term attains its minimum at $t=\frac{\epsilon\ln(n)}{V}$, which has to be small enough (and with $V \sim Cn$ it is possible as long as we take $n$ large enough). But then, at $t=\frac{\epsilon\ln(n)}{V}$, the probability is bounded by

$$\exp\left(-\frac{(\epsilon\ln(n))^2}{2V}\right) \sim \exp\left(-\frac{(\epsilon\ln(n))^2}{2Cn}\right) \rightarrow 1 \quad \text{as } \, n \rightarrow \infty,$$
which is not very helpful.

Can I get large deviations for this sum?